# How to select a number in a comma separated string?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have a column in my MySQL table. The column name is "attached_products", now, for example I have some records there and the attached_products have a value "1,16,164,1645", how do I select all records with "16"?

I tried the where clause, it went something like:

```
select * from websites where attached_products like '%16%'
```

but it also select the records with 164 and 21645.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: This is a many to one relationship - you need a table to relate the attached products to the items in this table.  @Mihai has your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since you are using a bad design for your database you could use, like you said:

```
SELECT * FROM `websites` WHERE (`attached_products` LIKE '%,16,%' OR `attached_products` LIKE '16,%' OR `attached_products` LIKE '%,16' OR `attached_products`='16');
```

but you should consider redesigning your database for easier selects. You can add another table with only those attached products like:

```
table 1
id | etc ... | etc .... |

attached_products
id | id_product | product
```

where id_product is from table 1 and product is the product id

Comment: Yah I think you're right, the I'm the new developer of this system. I'm thinking of redesigning the database.

Comment: ... or `attached_products` = '16'

Answer (score 0):

You could try `select * from websites where attached_products like '%,16,%'`

A better solution would be to create a new table to store this relationship (containing the product and attached product IDs)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`WHERE FIND_IN_SET('16', attached_products);`

Comment: You can do some test, anyway, it is best to redesign the db.

Answer (score 0):

select * from websites where (select substr(attached_products, ',')) = 16. But the good solution is redesigning